# How to make input value to be a global variable?

Tags: javascript, input, global-variables, local-variables

newbie here.

```
<input id="inte1" onchange="getNum1(this.value)">
<input id="inte2" onchange="getNum2(this.value)">
```

Want to make the 2 input into global variables, I tried:

```
function getNum1(e){ changeable = e; }; 
getNum1(); 
console.log(changeable);
```

and also tried:

```
function getNum1(e){ window.changeable = e; };
getNum1(); 
console.log(window.changeable);
```

It doesn't work, please help, thanks!

Comment: You're logging values immediately rather than on the function invocation, move the log into the function and you'll see that it works.

Answer (score 1):

What you have works fine. The problem is you're trying to log it before it's created. the variable doesn't exist until the onchange event is fired and you're logging it to the console immediately.

later, after the onchange event, it will exist. here's proof:

```js
function getNum1(e){ window.changeable = e; };
```

```html
<input id="inte1" onchange="getNum1(this.value)">
<button onclick=alert(changeable);>Get value of "changable" global variable</button>
```